# delete all the node value is 'x' in a singly linked list by Python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, linked-list

```
def dele(node,target):
 if not node:
     return
 if node.val == target:
     node.next = node.next.next
     node.next = None
 dele(node.next,target)
 return node
```

This code doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what should i change on the recursion rule? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific with the issue you're seeing. What's the error/message/result you're seeing?  Is there an error being thrown or is the result just not what you expect?

There's a lot that could cause this to not work properly. First, I don't think you need the `node.next = node.next.next` line, since you set `node.next` to None right after anyways.  You also need to store some kind of temporary node that allows you to keep track of the previous node, as you'll need to modify its `next` field if you delete its `next` node.

I haven't tested, but you could try something like:

```
def dele(node,target, prev):
 if not node:
     return
 if node.val == target:
     # set the previous node's next field to the current node's next field so that we skip over the current node (which we're removing) when iteraitng over the list
     prev.next = node.next
     # set current node to None
     node = None
     # continue to next node, passing in the node preceding this node (since we're deleting this node, the node before it will also be the node before the next item in the list)
     dele(node.next,target, prev)
 else:
     # keep running on the next node, but pass the current one as previous, as we don't delete it
     dele(node.next, target, node)
 return node
```